# Windows switches monitors all of a sudden (Windows 10, measurement system)

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, power-management, screensaver

we have a measurement system running at a factory. The system setup consists of (roughly):

1. User monitor
2. Measurement monitor

The program just displays a sine-pattern on the measurement monitor so we can do some deflectometry on it.
**Now the problem is that windows changes the monitors after around 36-42 hours in automation mode and we don't know why.**
(The sine-pattern appears on the user monitor all of a sudden)

The performance settings are all on "high performance" and the screen saver is turned off.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the underlying cause of this?

Thank you!

Comment: Windows wouldn't do that by itself. Some event might have happened, perhaps a reboot, power surge, or perhaps some software is responsible for that. If you don't know what happened, you could start with examining the Event Viewer. How is the Measurement monitor connected to the PC, and is it possible that it was turned off, however briefly?

Comment: Remove (or move to the bottom and mark as 'additional information') the clutter about measurements. This question is really: Why does Windows 10 re-detect my multiple monitor layout?

Add details:
What is your graphics driver type and version?
How are the monitors connected? HDMI, DisplayPort, DVI, VGA, composite?